# Efficient way to randomize data model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, object, random, shuffle

Creating a programming schedule based on videos in object model.
I want to run a task every day to shuffle this model so the programming each day would be different.

I am aware of 
`product.shuffle.all` for ex. but I want the order to be saved one time each day to do so vs on each server call.

I am thinking to add an attribute to each product, named order which would be an integer to order by. How would I shuffle just product.order for all products in this case?

Would this be the most efficient way? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `random` parameter of `shuffle`. It allows for stable randomization:

```
# When the Random object's seed is different, multiple runs result in different outcome:

pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].shuffle(random: Random.new)
=> [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 7, 2]
pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].shuffle(random: Random.new)
=> [1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2]


# When the Random object is created with the same seed, multiple runs return the same result:

pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
```

By basing the seed e.g. on the number of day in the year you can determine when the results randomization changes. You can (obviously) restore the randomization for any given day if you need to do so.

Comment: ah! this is an interesting approach. in this case, could i do --
products = products.shuffle(random: Random.new(Data.today.yday())

for users to all get the same shuffled products array each time day changes?

Comment: Yes, as log as both seed and the products list stay the same; the latter might be an obstacle.

Comment: this works, since products changing allowing for a shuffle to include new products makes sense. this is great! thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do would be best solved with a combination of the gem [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) along with your `product.shuffle.all` and an `update_attributes` call to the DB. That way you can view past versions as they are updated in your DB.

Comment: thanks! once i do a shuffle on the products, wouldn't i need to associate a shuffled order value to the products.order attribute for each product? after this, then run update_attributes?

Comment: the idea being if you shuffle the attributes and update the model with the different order of attributes, then you can save the new order and paper trail will keep track of the change.